# Ubuntu for devices terminal font size / any font size

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I have installed Ubuntu on my Nexus 7. Kudos to the team for a painless install.

I cannot change the default font (but that is a small problem).  I cannot change the terminal font from incredibly small - which is a big problem.  Has anyone any solutions?

To clarify, by 'terminal' I mean the black window with a prompt in which I can type commands (eg 'ls -l') and get text output (ie directory listing).  The font in this is only readable from very close up.

Ubuntu 15.04 r1,Asus Nexus 7 (2013) Wi-Fi)

Thanks in advance

Comment: terminal as in , gnome-terminal ? the one within graphical shell ?

Comment: I have to be careful with terminology.  I mean the black window with a prompt in which I can type commands (eg ls -l) and get text output (ie directory listing).